# Join using a LIKE clause is taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the TSQL below:

```
create table #IDs (id varchar(100))
insert into #IDs values ('123')
insert into #IDs values ('456')
insert into #IDs values ('789')
insert into #IDs values ('1010')

create table #Notes (Note varchar(500))
insert into #Notes values ('Here is a note for 123')
insert into #Notes values ('A note for 789 here')
insert into #Notes values ('456 has a note here')
```

I want to find all the IDs that are referenced in the #Notes table.  This works:

```
select #IDs.id from #IDs inner join #Notes on #Notes.note like '%' + #IDs.id + '%'
```

However, there are hundreds of thousands of records in both tables and the query does not complete.  I was thinking about FreeText searching, but I don't think it can be applied here.  A cursor takes too long to run as well (I think it will take over one month).  Is there anything else I can try? I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: if that ID is present in each row in the #Notes table, make a change to your schema definition. Create a stored procedure to find the ID within the text. And then use a trigger to fill the new ID column on every insert or update. Now you can join directly. Currently the DBMS has no choice than to scan one of the tables for each row in the other table, because you are using a function within your condition (+ is a function). Since the ID can be anywhere within the string, the DBMS can't use any indexes.

Comment: `LIKE` with a leading wildcard isn't SARGable, so there's really isn't a lot. Searching a column that appears to be free type for a specific value like that rarely performs well unless you are using something like a Fulltext index. Ideally, however, you should be fixing the design so your `Notes` table has a column for the ID it is related to.

Comment: Note that `LIKE '%789%'` will return '789' rows, and '1789' rows, and '7892' rows, etc.

Comment: @Larnu, it is a third party system, which I cannot change and the third party will not change.    How would I use a freetext index here?

Comment: @jarlh, yes that is the other problem.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can't change the system, then presumably you won't be able to add indexes to the database either, including [Fulltext indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Your sample data is far too simplistic to demonstrate the issues you face. Add to your item IDs the values "1" and "10" and include them in some notes.

Comment: *"it is a third party system, which I cannot change"*: No, since you are creating temporary tables (#), you can change them at any time.

Comment: @w0051977 the problem isn't the join, it's the bad join condition that forces a full table scan. No index can accelerate searches in the middle of a field. Since you use temporary tables you can fix the schema. Even if you can't generate proper tables from the start, you can extract the IDs stored in `Note` into a separate, indexed table. Instead of the M*N comparisons your query has to do now, you'll have something like `M*(logN +1)`.

Comment: @w0051977 SQL Server can use Python scripts and modules since 2017, which offers a far better way of parsing `Note` than the extremely limited `LIKE` patterns. Worst case, you can use a regular expression to extract the first number in the notes. For more complex cases you could use one of the powerful text manipulation packages to extract the ID and store it in an indexed field

Comment: @w0051977 if you really can't modify or create new temp tables (why? that's an extreme restriction), you'd still be better off performing the text manipulation in a script, to extract the ID and match records on that.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the input is only one aspect of the solution.
By splitting the text to tokens you indeed increase the number of records, but in the same time you enable equality join, which can be implemented using Hash Join.
You should get the query results in a few minutes top, basically the time it takes to your system to do a full scan on both tables, plus some processing time.
No need for temp tables.
No need for indexes.

```
Select id
from #IDS 
where id in (select w.value 
             from #Notes as n
             cross apply string_split(n.Note, ' ') as w
            )
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e61324198d9d70c08288bec35aa083b1)

Per the OP request -
Here is a code that handles more complicated scenario, where an id could contain various characters (as defined by @token_char) and the separators are potentially all other characters

```
declare @token_char varchar(100) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
;
with cte_notes as
(
    select  Note
           ,replace(translate(Note,@token_char,space(len(@token_char))),' ','') as non_token_char
                
    from    #Notes
)
select  id
from    #IDS 
where   id in
        (
            select  w.value 
            from    cte_notes as n
                    cross apply string_split(translate(n.Note,n.non_token_char,space(len(n.non_token_char))),' ') as w
            where   w.value != ''
        )
```

The [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afec2faadc17ef1ca59c5ab3feb2dae9) data sample was altered accordingly, to reflect the change

Comment: I'm currently on my cellphone.  Just make sure that the execution plan is using Hash Join.

Comment: This is very fast (runs in 1 second!) +1.

Comment: I have checked and there is not always a space after the id. Plus the id field is a varchar and their are occasionally letters in it. I realize I did not explain this in the question. Are you able to modify your answer? I am also looking into how your query can be changed.

Comment: (1) What does it mean "there is not always a space after the id"?. If you mean that id might be the last token, so it is not an issue. (2) If you mean that the id is a combination of letters and digits, then once again, it is not an issue since we are comparing tokens (strings separated by spaces)

Comment: #Notes.Note could contain: "456(this is an id number) has a note here" or "456[01/01/2022] has a note here".  Does that make sense?

Comment: See updated answer. I assume you don't know what are all the characters that might separate an id from the rest of the text, but you do know what characters ids are made of.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this search often you may want to explore using a wonderful (if underused) feature of SQL Server called 'Full Text Search.' To quote Microsoft:

> A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to
> return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less
> against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are
> returned.'
> I have seen searches go from minutes to seconds using this feature.

You would need to create a Full Text Search Catalog and then create indexs on the tables you want to search. It's not hard and will take you a few minutes to learn how to do this.

This is a good starting point:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

I would apply `CTE` with `string_split` to filter out all alphabetic components and then join #ID table with the result of the CTE by id column. The query was tested on a sample of 1 mm rows.

```
With CTE As (
    Select T.value As id
    From #Notes Cross Apply String_Split(Note,' ') As T
    Where Try_Convert(Int, T.value) Is Not Null
)
Select I.id 
From #IDs As I Inner Join CTE On (I.id=CTE.id)
```

If you just want to extract a numeric value from a string, in this case `join` is excessive.

```
Select T.value As id, #Notes.Note 
From #Notes Cross Apply String_Split(Note,' ') As T
Where Try_Convert(Int, T.value) Is Not Null And T.value Like '%[0-9]%'
```

| id | Note |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Here is a note for 123 |
| 789 | A note for 789 here |
| 456 | 456 has a note here |

No matter what, under the given circumstances, I would use `join` to filter out those numbers that are not represented in #IDs table.

```
With CTE As (
    Select distinct(id) As id
    From #IDs
)
Select T.value As id, #Notes.Note 
From #Notes Cross Apply String_Split(Note,' ') As T
            Inner Join CTE On (T.value=CTE.id)
Where Try_Convert(Int, T.value) Is Not Null 
      And T.value Like '%[0-9]%'
```

If the string contains brackets or parenthesis instead of spaces like this:
"456(this is an id number) has a note here" or "456[01/01/2022]"
as last resorts (since it degrades performance) you can use TRANSLATE to replace those brackets with spaces as follows:

```
With CTE As (
    Select distinct(id) As id
    From #IDs
)
Select T.value As id, #Notes.Note 
From #Notes Cross Apply String_Split(TRANSLATE(Note,'[]()','    '),' ') As T
            Inner Join CTE On (T.value=CTE.id)
Where Try_Convert(Int, T.value) Is Not Null 
      And T.value Like '%[0-9]%'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80c1cf91c192d6278b5db884d3bf30b3)

Comment: This will be even worse. Instead of matching M*N rows, the query will have to match M*N*WordCount, when it's already known that only one of those words is relevant

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos All words will be filtered out before the matching. Extracting the numeric using string_split and try_convert is a pretty fast approach. Is there any other solution to include in the result set only id's presented in #ID table without using matching under the given conditions?

Comment: so it is still unconvincing that under given conditions the answer deserves -2 in the absence of any alternative. :)

Comment: There are alternatives. The original question is a far better alternative. This answer *multiplies* the necessary operations. Splitting and `TRY_CONVERT` still multiply the rows and require processing of all of them to eliminate the non-numeric values. The other answer offers another alternative

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos By alternative, I meant how to eliminate unnecessary ids without using matching under given conditions. Regarding other things, any solution has its cons and pros, it is a little slower than the other with forced single-threaded execution, but covers cases where a string has multiple numbers.

Comment: While I found the syntax problematic (why use a distinct on the IDs table? What about handling duplicate due to multiple ocurrences of the same ID etc.),  @Panagiotis Kanavos claim is actually false, since it ignores the possible join algorithms for your solution vs. the original OP attempt.

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz Duplicates can lead to performance degradation during the Join operation, so i handled duplicates in CTE since hypothetically they can be present in any number in #IDs table for which there is no primary or unique key on id column.

Comment: @w0051977 Have you tried the last query in the answer?